# Vuejs list loop - add class based on properties of each child

Tags: javascript, drop-down-menu, vuejs2

I have a list from the data fetched from an API. I would like to check if each element in list has a sub-element/child or not, and then add a class based on decision.

My attempt:

```
<template>
    ...
    <ul>
        <li v-for="nav in navigation" :class="{conditionalClass: isNavDropdown(nav)}">xxxx</li>
    </ul>
    ...
</template>
```

And then in `methods` I have this function:

```
<script>
    ...
    methods: {
        isNavDropdown: function (nav) {
            return nav.children[0] !== null
        }
    }
    ...
</script>
```

This doesn't work. Printing `nav` in console gives me a strange object with elements like `reactiveGetter()` and `reactiveSetter()` (multiple of them).

Is it even possible to achieve such a thing with vuejs? Or do I need to use javascript tricks to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check that within your HTML itself, without the need of a separate method.

```
...
<li v-for="nav in navigation" :class="{conditionalClass: nav.children}">xxxx</li>
...
```